# How can I find exactly what characters are in a filename?

Tags: windows, file-management, unicode

In Windows, file names are stored in Unicode.  Since there are distinct Unicode code points that look identical, it is not always possible to tell exactly what the file name actually is.  For example, two files might have [what appears to be the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43381802/886887) even though the operating system considers the names to be distinct.

Given a file, what is the easiest way to find out what Unicode code points are in the file name?

Answer (score 1):

So far, the only solution I've found is to copy-and-paste the file name from Explorer into a suitable web service, such as [this Unicode code converter.](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/)

Right-click on the file and select "rename".  Press Control-C to copy the file name.

Open the web site linked above and paste the file name into the text box at the top of the page.  Press the "Hex code points" button to perform the conversion.  The hexadecimal representation of the code points will appear in the "Hexadecimal" text box at the bottom of the page.

You can then [look these code points up on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Code_point_planes_and_blocks).

Comment: standard ANSI Latin characters should all be between 0000 and 007F. Any character out of that range is suspect. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF

Comment: @Frank, do you mean in the context of the linked question?  In the general case there's no reason to expect a filename to be limited to ANSI Latin characters, particularly if you're not in an English-speaking country.

Comment: Indeed. The concern is look-alike characters, so in general, any character that comes from another page/plane than the rest of the string is suspect, if it truly appears to look the same as a character available within the page. In this case, the `i` in `MailClient.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a script to automate the execution of tasks that could alternatively be executed one-by-one by a human operator.

There are IMHO two useful scripts in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771986/3439404) to the original question on Stack Overflow [**Windows / NTFS: Two files with identical long-names in the same directory?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43381802/886887).

---

**Addendum** for the sake of history completion. Here's another approach to solve the OQ (*my absolutely first attempt*). The script compares strings (e.g. filenames) of the same length character by character and outputs different (or non-ANSI) ones:

```
param( [string[]] $strArr = @('ΗGreek', 'НCyril', 'HLatin') )
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$strDiff = ''
$arrDiff = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $strArr.Count; $i++) {
  for ($j=$i+1; $j -lt $strArr.Count; $j++) {
    if ( ($i -ne $j) -and ( $strArr[$i].Length -eq $strArr[$j].Length) ) {
      for ($k=0; $k -lt $strArr[$i].Length; $k++) {
        if ( #  -and # different characters AND 
            ( [int][char]$strArr[$i][$k] -gt 255 -or 
                [int][char]$strArr[$j][$k] -gt 255 ) )
        { # at least one is out of pure ASCII range
          if ( $strArr[$i][$k] -ne $strArr[$j][$k] ) {$Eq = '#'} else {$Eq = '='}
          if ( $strDiff -notmatch $strArr[$i][$k] ) { $strDiff += $strArr[$i][$k]}
          if ( $strDiff -notmatch $strArr[$j][$k] ) { $strDiff += $strArr[$j][$k]}
          $arrDiff += "{0,4} {1} U+{2:x4} $Eq {3} U+{4:x4} {5} {6}" -f 
            ($k+1), $strArr[$i][$k], [int][char]$strArr[$i][$k], 
                        $strArr[$j][$k], [int][char]$strArr[$j][$k], 
                        $strArr[$i], $strArr[$j]
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
if ($strDiff.Length -ne 0 ) { 
    if ( Get-Command -Name Get-CharInfo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) {
      $strDiff | Get-CharInfo
    }
    ''         # an indent line
    $arrDiff
}
```

**Output** (slightly difficult to survey…) The first table (with headers) is output from (adjusted) custom [`Get-CharInfo` cmdlet](http://poshcode.org/5234); the latter one (without headers) is explained below:

```
PS D:\PShell> .\SO\43381802.ps1 ( Get-childitem -path 'C:\testC\43381802' ).Name

Char CodePoint        Category Description
---- ---------        -------- -----------
   e U+0065    LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter E
   е U+0435    LowercaseLetter Cyrillic Small Letter Ie
   M U+004D    UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter M
   М U+041C    UppercaseLetter Cyrillic Capital Letter Em

   8 e U+0065 # е U+0435 MailClient.txt MailCliеnt.txt
   1 M U+004d # М U+041c MailClient.txt МailClient.txt
   1 M U+004d # М U+041c MailClient.txt МailCliеnt.txt
   8 e U+0065 # е U+0435 MailClient.txt МailCliеnt.txt
   1 M U+004d # М U+041c MailCliеnt.txt МailClient.txt
   8 е U+0435 # e U+0065 MailCliеnt.txt МailClient.txt
   1 M U+004d # М U+041c MailCliеnt.txt МailCliеnt.txt
   8 е U+0435 = е U+0435 MailCliеnt.txt МailCliеnt.txt
   1 М U+041c = М U+041c МailClient.txt МailCliеnt.txt
   8 e U+0065 # е U+0435 МailClient.txt МailCliеnt.txt
```

*Explanation* of the latter line:

- `8`              a character position in both compared strings
- `e U+0065`       a character itself and it's Unicode codepoint (1st string)
- `#`              `#` or `=` (different or the same but non-ANSI, respectively)
- `е U+0435`       a character itself and it's Unicode codepoint (2nd string)
- `МailClient.txt` 1st string itself
- `МailCliеnt.txt` 2nd string itself

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste the names into notepad++, then select ASCII-->HEX from the basic converter under plugins-->converter. It will not convert UTF-8 to ANSI so the bytes are preserved.

Note you have to select view-->Show symbol-->all characters because NPP can't display HEX and you have to select all the characters. I.e. the non-printing characters are also just bytes that need converting. For example in the screenshot line 1 converts into line 2.

[image: screenshot].

(ignore the CR-LF newline characters in this example)